# Evaluating a definite integral using complex integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

How would I solve (evaluate) an integral using methods of **complex integration**, in particular  $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{2+\cos x}dx$ ?
If the boundaries went from $0$ to $2\pi$, I could use the standard integration contour where $|z|=1$ (which would be possible to execute if it was an even function).

*Edit*: I'm aware using a different method would be much easier and the solution is obvious, but I'm particularly interested in using *complex integration* because I'm unsure how to approach it. The question is not this integral specifically, but integrals similar to this one which I used as an example (boundaries not forming a full unit circle). *Point being not the solution part, but the thought process of it using said method.*

Comment: The primitive is immediate, why to incomodate complex integration?

Comment: One way you could do this (but maybe not the best way) would be to use the substitution $2x = u$

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-calculate-integral-between-0-and-2pi-of-1-sinx-2cosx-3-using-the-residue-theorem-I-know-that-I-can-change-sinx-and-cosx-by-z-2-1-2iz-respectively-z-2-1-2z-but-I-think-that-I-am-missing-something

Comment: @enzotib it may be for precisely that reason. This makes it a good candidate to validate an answer with.

Comment: I've seen in it on some exams before (complex integration being specified), also I'm really curious about it, not just this specific one, rather in general. I've done some research but I couldn't find anything about it yet.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716318/integrating-int-02-pi-fracd-theta3-sin-theta-cos-theta?rq=1

Comment: Yes but the boundaries have to vary from 0 to $2\pi$ in order to use the $|z|=1$ contour. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you thought about my suggestion of just enforcing the $u$ substitution? Does it do any good?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Actually yes, I got get the integral in the form needed, and proceeded to use residue theorem to calculate the solution but I didn't get the correct answer. I think I did everything right, I can't see where I might've made the mistake. I would post that one here but I don't want to confuse people by a possibly wrong answer. Is there a way I can send it to you privately to take a look at it? I'm new to this site, pardon my lack of experience, I'm still getting the hang of it.

Comment: @saelsx add your calculations to your question

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x}{2+\cos x}~dx=\left.-\int_0^\pi\frac{d(2+\cos x)}{2+\cos x}=-\log(2+\cos x)\right|_0^\pi=-(\log1-\log3)=\log3$$

Thus, why to use complex integration here? It surely won't be any faster or easier...and you'll have to integrate over the upper part of the unit circle...

Comment: The math class I'm taking is focused on complex analysis and methods different than we've used before. It was an old exam question so it peaked my interest and I was unsure how to approach it.